# Embedding Tex inside JavaScript and/or C#

Tags: embedding, javascript

Firstly, I'm completely new to using `TeX`, so please bear with my ignorance. I am writing an application that will require the program to display some symbols, namely those in the `MusixTeX` library, but I don't know how to go about doing the displaying. Can anyone guide me as to how I might write code to do this? I'll be programming in either `C#` or `JavaScript`, so an answer for either (or both) of those languages would be really helpful. As I said, I'm really new to using `TeX` in general, so the more detailed of an answer you can give, the better. I'm not afraid of work, so if it's a laborious process, that's fine. I'd just like to be able to do it!

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at http://www.mathjax.org/ 
This is an open source javascript display engine